# EPERM on appendFile on network drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

Application has to store log data to the network drive.
When the drive is hosted under Windows, all is OK.
When the drive is hosted under Mac, read/write is OK, but append gets EPERM, so log does not work at all.
The code is quite trivial

```
fs.appendFileSync('xxx.txt', 'zzzzzzzz');
```

How to correctly append the data ? The file usually too big to be loaded into  the memory.

Update: read-write-delete-create is Ok ! Only opening with append fails

Comment: Curious if you have tried fs.appendFile ?  Probably same result, but worth a try.

Comment: Any append fails. Even createWriteStream with the flag 'a'. However, writing without such flag works fine

Comment: Have you done ls -le xxx.txt ? You may have an ACL that is conflicting.

Comment: ls -le xxx.txt gives -rw-rw-rw-

Comment: Underneath you don't see anything like  0: user:root deny append.  If not, then I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with Luc Gendriks.**EPERM** occurs when you do not have enough permissions on the file/folder.Try the following

**Code:**

```
 fs.chmod('xxx.txt', 777, function(err){
  if(err){
   console.log(err);
   return;
  }
  fs.appendFileSync('xxx.txt', 'zzzzzzzz');
});
```

**Reference**:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmodsync_path_mode
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_file_data_options

Hope this helps.

Comment: The same result - EPERM. Under windows append is separate permission. Probably, node might have a bug when run under windows which uses hfs-drive or similar.

Comment: I said twice - read-write-delete-create is Ok ! Only opening with append fails.

Comment: This does not work under Windows when using appendFile or appendFileSync.  The fact that appendFile and appendFileSync can create the file, but not write to it is likely a bug with NodeJS for their Windows build.  Too bad.  You can appendFile or appendFileSync to a local, temporary file, then copy it to your desired destination.  Still not ideal, though.

Answer (score 1):

EPERM stands for Error - PERMission: nodejs is not allowed to write to the log file. Check if the application has access to the log file and change it so that the node application may write to the log file.

On a mac, you can do `chmod 777 somefile.log` (note that this allowed anyone that has access to your filesystem to write to the log file).

Probably the windows server has created the log file and the mac server is not allowed to access it (because it is not the owner and write permission is not public).

Answer (score 1):

May be the file is used by some other process? (So access/operation is denied)